# Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:createMockableJar]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android App Development. When I tried to create a new project,Android Project...the following message popped up:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:createMockableJar]
```

This is the screenshot of my project:

[image]

Comment: Please paste your build.gradle dependencies too +, add the logs here.

Answer (score -1):

if you using com.google.gms:google-services plz flowing my solution and resolve you problem

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

          classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```